# Can this subset of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ be expressed as a Cartesian product of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of all real numbers, and let $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ denote the set of all infinite sequences (or $\omega$-tuples) of real numbers. Then is it possible to express the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ as a Cartesian product of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?
$$\{ x= (x_i)_{i\in Z^+} | x_2 = x_3 \}.$$

Comment: Why does it matter that the second element is equal to the third?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. In particular, suppose we had sets $S_i$ such that your set was $S_1\times S_2 \times S_3 \ldots$ - that is, it could be written as
$$S=\{(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\,|\,\forall i\in \mathbb{Z}^+[x_i\in S_i]\}$$
To show that this is impossible, notice that if $x_i$ and $y_i$ were sequences in $S$, any sequence $z_i$ such that, for all $i$, either $z_i=x_i$ or $z_i=y_i$ held, would be in $S$ as well - that is, if it was pieced together by taking coordinates from either $x$ or $y$, each element would have clearly come from the proper $S_i$ and hence the sequence would be in $S$.

Your set does not satisfy this and is hence not a Cartesian product; in particular, suppose we have two sequences $x$ and $y$ starting
$$x=(0,2,2,9,\ldots)$$
$$y=(0,3,3,9,\ldots)$$
this would imply that $2\in S_2$ and $3\in S_2$ and $2\in S_3$ and $3\in S_3$. Thus, we would conclude that
$$z=(0,2,3,9,\ldots)$$
must also be in the set, were it simply a Cartesian product - but it is not, because $2\neq 3$.

In a Cartesian product, you would only be able to place restrictions on each element alone; the values that $x_2$ could take on could not depend on the value of $x_3$, which they do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, there is a trivial isomorphism from this subset (call it $X$) to $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$, and $$\mathbb{R}^{\omega}=\prod_\omega \mathbb{R}.$$

However, it is quite likely that I have misunderstood your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so..  Your set is is $\mathbb R \times D \times \mathbb R ^\omega $,  where $D\subset \mathbb R ^2$ is the "diagonal",  ie the following set:

$\{(a,a)|a \in \mathbb R\}$.   So your question is equivalent to can you express $D$ as a cartesion product of elements of $\mathbb R$, and you can't...unless you allow me an uncountable union of such elements.